# objective-c : when delegating webview, how to get webViewDidChange work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, webkit

I have the following interface

```
   #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
   #import <WebKit/WebView.h> 
   #import <WebKit/WebFrame.h>
   #import <WebKit/WebEditingDelegate.h>
   @interface CounterController: WebView 
   {
        WebView* myWebView;
   }
   @property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *myWebView;
   @end
```

and this implementation

```
   #import "CounterController.h"
   @implementation CounterController

   -(id)init
    {
    [super init];
    [super setEditingDelegate:self];
        return self;
    }

    - (void)webViewDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello World");
    }
```

the HTML file which is run by webview has this editable area

```
  <div id="bar" contenteditable="true">
  dddddd
  </div>
```

when I run the script it works fine and the editable content is editable; however, "hello world" is not printed in the consol so I assume that the delegate method "webViewDidChange" is not working!

am I doing the delegate right, why this method "webViewDidChange" is not working? and how to get it work?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't try to subclass `WebView` for this; create a proper separate controller object. You should find that the editing delegate works great then.

Comment: Thanks, I think you gave the correct answer ;however, I cant understand your answer since it is so pref for me because I am beginner, anyway, I will try to understand -by the way I bought your videos and watched many of them last week- Thanks

Comment: Excellent, hope the videos help you! :)

Comment: can you explain what you mean, 'don't try to subclass Webview for this'?  can you give an example of a "proper" separate controller object?

Comment: The original question involves subclassing WebView. It's extremely rare that you want to do this. WebView is an NSView subclass, part of the view layer. For controlling editing, you want an object that exists at the controller layer. Perhaps a subclass of NSViewController.